# This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix, erc-20

I followed the tutorial found here: https://steemit.com/ethereum/@maxnachamkin/how-to-create-your-own-ethereum-token-in-an-hour-erc20-verified

I tried to create this contract using Remix. I had to make some changes to the code posted on the website because it was out of date. I had to change throw to revert() and changed sha3() to keccak256().

Remix will not create the contract. It says: "This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created."

What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Token {
    function totalSupply() constant public returns (uint totalSupply);
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant public returns (uint balance);
    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address _spender, uint _value) public returns (bool success);
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant public returns (uint remaining);
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint _value);
}



contract StandardToken is Token {

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        //Default assumes totalSupply can't be over max (2^256 - 1).
        //If your token leaves out totalSupply and can issue more tokens as time goes on, you need to check if it doesn't wrap.
        //Replace the if with this one instead.
        //if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
            balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
            balances[_to] += _value;
            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        //same as above. Replace this line with the following if you want to protect against wrapping uints.
        //if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
        if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
            balances[_to] += _value;
            balances[_from] -= _value;
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
            Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant public returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant public returns (uint256 remaining) {
      return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    mapping (address => uint256) balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
}


//name this contract whatever you'd like
contract TestToken is StandardToken {

    function() public {
        //if ether is sent to this address, send it back.
        revert();
    }

    /* Public variables of the token */

    /*
    NOTE:
    The following variables are OPTIONAL vanities. One does not have to include them.
    They allow one to customise the token contract & in no way influences the core functionality.
    Some wallets/interfaces might not even bother to look at this information.
    */
    string public name = "TestToken";                   //fancy name: eg Simon Bucks
    uint8 public decimals = 0;                //How many decimals to show. ie. There could 1000 base units with 3 decimals. Meaning 0.980 SBX = 980 base units. It's like comparing 1 wei to 1 ether.
    string public symbol = "TTT";                 //An identifier: eg SBX
    string public version = "1.0";       //human 0.1 standard. Just an arbitrary versioning scheme.

//
// CHANGE THESE VALUES FOR YOUR TOKEN
//

//make sure this function name matches the contract name above. So if you're token is called TutorialToken, make sure the //contract name above is also TutorialToken instead of ERC20Token

    function TestToken() public {
        balances[msg.sender] = 100000;               // Give the creator all initial tokens (100000 for example)
        totalSupply = 100000;                        // Update total supply (100000 for example)
        name = "TestToken";                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        decimals = 0;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
        symbol = "TTT";                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }

    /* Approves and then calls the receiving contract */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

        //call the receiveApproval function on the contract you want to be notified. This crafts the function signature manually so one doesn't have to include a contract in here just for this.
        //receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _tokenContract, bytes _extraData)
        //it is assumed that when does this that the call *should* succeed, otherwise one would use vanilla approve instead.
        if(!_spender.call(bytes4(bytes32(keccak256("receiveApproval(address,uint256,address,bytes)"))), msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData)) { revert(); }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `totalSupply()` implementation is missing. Seems like autogenerated getters  do not count. So you need to explicitly create the function.

```
contract StandardToken is Token {
    uint256 _totalSupply;

    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 totalSupply) {
        totalSupply = _totalSupply;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Agree with Andrey, it's because the `totalSupply` is declared as part of the Interface and then never defined. The inconsistency led me to check the pragma quickly, and it does not compile with  `0.4.4` due the presence of `revert`.

This

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Token {
    uint public totalSupply;
```

plus this near 59

```
// uint256 public totalSupply;
```

because it would be redundant.

I feel I should caution you about going ahead with something that is only superficially investigated. (No warranty). Consider using a current and well-reviewed set of contracts instead of tinkering with one that has errors in it. It's a lot of code to wade through in search of non-obvious oversights.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I was doing this for the learning experience rather than trying to create anything in particular. Do you have any recommendations on a current and well-reviewed set of contracts to play with to learn more about how all of this works?